# How to search serialized object as a database query?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I'm using SQLite database to store an object. In order to do that, I simply converted that object into byte[] and put it into the database.

But when I'm retrieving it from the database, I'm getting below error

**unrecognized token: "[B@457637e" (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM ContentList WHERE subjectNumber=0 AND subjectTypeNumber=0 AND content=[B@457637e**

to store byte[] a have created a coulmn which contain BLOB
initially i'm searching this object into an empty database

```
byte[] data = SerializationUtils.serialize(Object);
Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + 
    DbContract.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + DbContract.SUBJECT_NUMBER + "=" + subjectNumber + 
    " AND " + DbContract.SUBJECT_TYPE_NUMBER + "=" + subjectTypeNumber + " AND " + 
    DbContract.CONTENT + "=" + data, null);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide the byte array as an appropriate value to the query e.g. x'ff0099AA'.

e.g. consider the following SQL which DROPS and CREATES a table then INSERTS a few rows with BLOBS and then searches for one of those blobs :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table_with_blob;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_with_blob (blob_column BLOB);
INSERT INTO table_with_blob VALUES(x'FFFFFFFF'),(x'EEEEEEEE'),(x'DDDDDDDD');
SELECT * FROM table_with_blob WHERE blob_column = x'EEEEEEEE';
```

This results in the single row, as expected, being found :-
[image]

- *Commands commented out so the result is shown  due to how the tool works*
- Blobs aren't that good to work with for example if you wanted to search for any BLOBS that are the equivalent of LIKE x'EE%' (note that won't work and will result in a syntax error) you would do something like :-

  - `SELECT *,rowid AS rid FROM table_with_blob WHERE substr(blob_column,1,1) =  x'EE';`
- *Noting that the start and length of the substr function represents the number of bytes not the number of characters/4bits/nibbles of the hex String.*

**The simplest way though, rather than writing a method to convert the byte array to a hex string, is to let the query convenience method do the conversion to a hex string on your behalf.**

So instead of:-

```
byte[] data = SerializationUtils.serialize(Object);
Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + 
    DbContract.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + DbContract.SUBJECT_NUMBER + "=" + subjectNumber + 
    " AND " + DbContract.SUBJECT_TYPE_NUMBER + "=" + subjectTypeNumber + " AND " + 
    DbContract.CONTENT + "=" + data, null);
```

You could have :-

```
byte[] data = SerializationUtils.serialize(Object);
String whereclause = DbContract.SUBJECT_NUMBER + "=? AND " +
    DbContract.SUBJECT_TYPE_NUMBER + "=? AND " +
    DbContract.CONTENT + "=?";
String[] whereargs = new String[]{subjectNumber,subjectTypeNumber,data}
Cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(
             DbContract.TABLE_NAME,
             null, //<<<< all columns
             whereclause,
             whereargs,
             null,null,null
);
```

- *Note the above code is in-principle code and has not been tested, it may therefore contain some errors.*
- When retrieving the data for content column you need to use `getBlob` method e.g. `mybytearray = getBlob(DbContract.CONTENT);`